# I tried to build the decision tree model on concatinated fatures. Getting the value error

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

**Concatinating the features**

```
enter code here

X_train_set4 = hstack((X_train_price, X_train_quantity,X_train_projects,X_train_categories_one_hot, 
                   X_train_subcategories_one_hot,X_train_states_one_hot, 
                   X_train_teacher_prefix_one_hot,X_train_grade_category_one_hot, 
                   X_train_tfidf_w2v_essay_vectors,X_train_tfidf_w2v_title_vectors)).tocsr()
X_test_set4 = hstack((X_test_price, X_test_quantity,X_test_projects,X_test_categories_one_hot, 
                  X_test_subcategories_one_hot,X_test_states_one_hot,X_test_teacher_prefix_one_hot, 
                  X_test_grade_category_one_hot,X_test_tfidf_w2v_essay_vectors, 
                  X_test_tfidf_w2v_title_vectors)).tocsr()
X_cv_set4 = hstack((X_cv_price, X_cv_quantity, X_cv_projects, X_cv_categories_one_hot, 
                X_cv_subcategories_one_hot, X_cv_states_one_hot, X_cv_teacher_prefix_one_hot, 
                X_cv_grade_category_one_hot, X_cv_tfidf_w2v_essay_vectors, 
                X_cv_tfidf_w2v_title_vectors)).tocsr()
```

**Printing the shape**

```
print("Set-4 Data Matrix")
print(X_train_set4.shape, Y_train.shape)
print(X_test_set4.shape, Y_test.shape)
print(X_cv_set4.shape, Y_cv.shape)
```

**Bulding the model**

```
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight='balanced')
parameters = {'max_depth':[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'min_samples_split':[5, 10, 100, 500]}

clf4 = GridSearchCV(dtc, parameters, cv=5, scoring='roc_auc', return_train_score='True')
clf4.fit(X_train_set4, Y_train)
```

*Error*

> Getting the value error. I tried to check for nan's, but unable to find for X_train. There are no nan's in Y_train

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
```

Comment: post the data, check np.isnan(np.min(x)) or np.isinf(np.max(x))